# fix error when passing string xyz-009 into javascript function

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, ecma262

So I am passing a string into a javascript function. for example:

```
function dothis(x,y,z){
    something
}

dothis(year,month,contract); // contract = "A10-009_xyz"
```

I know this has something to do with the way javascript deals with 08 and 09, but I am unsure of the best way to deal with it in my case.

the error I'm getting is

```
09 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant
dothis(2012, 01, A10-009_xyz);
```

I saw some people suggesting using `number(string)` or `parceInt("09","10")` but I'm unsure of how to impliment with this as the string will be changing a lot. Am I supposed to check the string before placing into the function and look for 08,09 and replace with the `parceInt()`?

Thanks for any help, suggestions etc appriciated.

Comment: Um, it is complaining when you are calling the method? That does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, I could be confused as I have never ran into this problem before. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you're quoting the string, it shouldn't cause a problem when calling the function. The problem must be with what the function does with `z`, you need to show that.

Comment: What you typed and what the error message shows seems like you are missing quotes.

Comment: In Javascript, if a number begins with `0`, it's treated as octal. But it shouldn't be interpreted as a number if you quote it. And you shouldn't call `parseInt()` if it's not supposed to be a number.

Comment: I updated my questions, I'm actually passing a variable into the function. I apologize, I don't know if this effects it but I'm using coldfusion to pass in variable to the function

Comment: Yea i didn't think either the parseInt or number functions would be of any help in my case.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you pass it as a variable or literal, as long as you quoted it when you assigned the variable.

Comment: Are you using `eval()`?

Comment: Ok, I guess I was assuming that js would interpret it as a string since the variable it-self was a string. Thanks!